# I cannot understand the definition of big O notation

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, definition

I am taking a Data Structure course this semester and I cannot understand the definition of big O notation.

The definition says, `f(n) = O(g(n))` if there exist positive constant `C` and `n0` such that
 `f(n)<=C*g(n)` for all `n > n0`. I understand why `n > n0`, it's talking about from the point `n0`, `f(n)` is always smaller than `c*g(n)`. But I cannot understand why `f(n)` is compared to `C*g(n)` but not just `g(n)`.

Can anyone explain please?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But why we have to influence the trend with c? Why not just simply compare f(n) and g(n).

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot understand why f(n) is compared to C*g(n) but not just g(n)

Because it represents the *order* of execution time. The constant `C` is more or less meaningless when comparing algorithms in this respect.

Consider two sorting algorithms. Bubble sort is O(n^2), whereas Quick sort is O(n log(n)). Both of these take time that is *proportional* to their order, but there will be some constant that you multiply by to get a reasonable approximation of the running time of the algorithm (and it may be a different value constant between the two).

However, for any values `C` for each of the algorithms, there will be some point (some value of `n`) beyond which Quick sort is always faster. This is what "big O notation" is all about. The constant `C` doesn't matter when you look at the bigger picture, and that's why it's disregarded.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I understand it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Because it allows for a much more succint and useful comparison.

Using `C` makes the definition such that it says

> `f` grows at roughly (asymptotically) the same speed as `g` (or slower)

Without the `C`, we'd lose the *"roughly (asymptotically)"* part. Without the `C`, we couldn't just say `f = O(n^2)`, we'd have to say something like `f = O(1.7 n^2)` (unless the factor happened to be 1, of course). That's not particularly useful.

Big O is generally used to talk about algorithm classes, and about ratios. `f = O(n^2)` says: "When you scale `n` twice, the computation scales 4 times." This would still be true for `O(4 n^2)` or `O(1.7 n^2)` or even `O(0.01 n^2)`.

The entire point of the Big O notation is to express *asymptotic* complexity—what *trends* there are when `n` gets large. We don't *care* whether it takes 4-times as much or half-as much at the same `n`; we care how it scales when `n` scales, and such scaling is invariant to a multiplicative constant.

Not to mention the fact that fixing the exact constant would be really difficult in specific cases. It's generally easy to show that e.g. an algorithm performs roughly `n` operations for each bit of input, and so has `n^2` complexity. But it would be quite painful to analyse whether it performs `3 n` operations for `n / 2` input elements and `2 n` operations for the other `n / 2` elements, or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It helps me a lot. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
big o = Worst,
BIG omega = Normal,
BIG theta = Good,

they just represent the scenario like BIG O means worst case scenario
For example in a loop 

    > For (int i =0 ;i <10000; i ++) 
    > break on some case 


BIG O will be 10000 if the break condition is not found.
```